# OnSignleTapUp event fires twice

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a Xamarin Android application with a GestureDetector. On my device (Sony Xperia S5303) and in emulators it works fine. However, on a Samsung Galaxy tablet, the OnSingleTapUp event is fired twice, even though I touch the screen just once. Since the event is checked by the OnSingleTapConfirmed, and the device behaves as if two taps were made, the following method is never called:

```
public bool OnSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
{
    if (PersistentContext.LoggedPlayer.Token)
    {
        if (simpleOnGestureListener.OnSingleTapConfirmed(e))
        {
             Move(e);
        }
        return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

The strange thing is, that when clicking on a button, the button method is called just once. Can anybody tell me what might cause this strange behaviour and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event)` instead. This way android makes sure it's a single tap and doesn't fire the event twice.

**Edit:** if you are determined to use `onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event)`, then you can use `event.getEventTime()`and if the time difference between the first and second events is less than a THRESHOLD like 200ms or something, consider it the unwanted second-time fired tap and ignore it.

**Edit 2:** Since I don't use Xamarin I might be totally wrong but I think you need to change your code like this: (I mean forget onSingleTapUp completely and move wyour whole code into onSingleTapConfirmed)

```
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
        if (PersistentContext.LoggedPlayer.Token)
        {
                Move(e);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Hope it helps and Good Luck!

Comment: If you read the question thoroughly, you will see that I am using onSingleTapConfirmed. The problem is, that even then the event is called twice. I made a simple workaround by implementing onDoubleTap, and assigning it the same functionality - since I had no use of onDoubleTap. However, even my colleagues have had repeated problems with Samsung devices. I wonder, why is Google not controlling Samsungs Android implementation a little bit more.

Comment: Yes, I see that, I dont use Xamarin but here what i see: the way you are using onSingleTapConfirmed is the problem. onSingleTapUp is running twice one step ahead and of course there is a confirmation for tap, so you are disabling the effect of onSingleTapConfirmed. I edit my answer with some piece of code and I hope it works for you

Comment: Actually, I have done just the same :) still, Samsung devices have fired the event twice. I know a similar issue occured on PhoneGap, as well. Maybe it has been updated in the newer Android/Xamarin versions. But I finished the project about half a year ago and did not return to it since, so I cannot confirm this.